# What is the best way to host WCF and ASP.NET together?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have an asp.net 3.5 site and I've just written some wcf services.  It is ok to just drop the .svc file right alongside my .aspx files or should I move my .svc files onto a separate virtual directory and IP and call it something like services.mydomain.com.

Just wondering what best practices are.  Maybe it doesn't make any difference?  I have a client app that will update the database that my web site uses.  It updates through an IIS hosted wcf service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it would be better to isolate the web service into a separate virtual directory and application pool. In this case the client application and the web service don't share the same AppDomain and if one fails the other will continue serving requests.

Answer (score 1):

In our project we tend to keep them in separate virtual directories. I like to regard the service as something that can be used by more than one client, and so I like the deployment and hosting of it separate from the client. Of course, if you just stick it in a separate virtual directory you can argue to what extent the hosting is separated, but at least it is separate on a logical level, and easily moved to separate physical hosting if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to have them in the same place - not least because it makes it hard to configure the appropriate level of security. It also makes configuration simpler as they won't share a `web.config`.